# How to use byte data-type in RenderScript without Allocations?

Tags: android, renderscript

How can I use `byte` datatype in RS layer on android? I'm targeting Android 4.1 and up for this.

I'm reading a image file in a `byte[]` in my Java class and intend to pass this `byte[]` to RenderScript for some processing and then get the `byte[]` data back in Java class. I'm quite aware of doing this stuff had the data been `int[]`. So in other words my question would be - what is the equivalent datatype of byte in RenderScript?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to use Allocation? Can you explain what your are doing with the byte datatype.

Comment: Have edited my question. I could Allocation too as far as I can do it in Android 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it as `char` in the .rs file. For instance, you can create a kernel that looks like this:

```
char __attribute__((kernel)) foo(char c) {
    return c + 1;
}
```

You will still need to create an `Allocation` in Java to pass that data to the kernel (reading and/or writing), and use `copyTo()`/`copyFrom()` to pass the `Byte` buffers back and forth.

Comment: Perfect. Just about what I was looking for. However when I send my `char[]` using `rsSendToClient` back to Java I get the `mData[]` in Big-Endian format. Is there a direct API in RenderScript to send/receive the data in Little-Endian format?

Comment: No. I still don't understand why you prefer rsSendToClient(). Since I work on RS, I know that this is the slowest path back to Java (rather than using Allocations and the associated copy routines. In the future, with `USAGE_SHARED` you may be able to even get zero-copy for data types other than Bitmaps.

Comment: Can I use `Allocation` in android 4.1? AFAIK (ref:Google IO 2013) `rsSetElementAt` API is recently added in android RS layer. Please correct me if I'm wrong. If not `rsSetElementAt`, then is there any other way to transfer `byte[]` between RS and Java layers?

Comment: You can, but I think there is a better way. Even for targeting 4.1, you should be using the support library. This lets you use the features of v18 on devices running v8 (FroYo) or higher. With the support library, you can use `rsSetElementAt()`.